# c++ static_assert fails on both branches of an 'if constexpr statement'

Tags: c++, c++17, type-traits, static-assert, compile-time-type-checking

I'm trying to determine at compile time if a specific type is of type **std::pair**.
When I compile the code below, I get the assertion fail on both branches (that is, both "HERE1", and "HERE2").
If I remove the static_asserts and uncomment the prints, I get what I expect:
That is "HERE1" for **is_pair_type<T::value_type>**, and "HERE2" for **is_pair_type< T >**.

I guess this means the compiler can't evaluate the expression at compile time, but I don't understand why.

**Using: MS VS2019, with MSVC version 14.29.30037**

Thanks.

```
template< class T >             struct is_pair : std::false_type {};
template< class T1, class T2 >  struct is_pair< std::pair< T1, T2 > > : std::true_type {};
template< class T >             struct is_pair_d : is_pair<typename std::decay<T>::type> {};
// a helper function for value
template<class T> struct is_pair_type {
    static constexpr bool const value = is_pair_d<T>::value;
};

int main()
{
    using T = std::map<int, float>;
    T blabla;

    if constexpr (is_pair_type<T>::value)
    {
        //std::cout << "HERE1" << "\n";
        static_assert(false, "HERE1");
    }
    else
    {
        //std::cout << "HERE2" << "\n";
        static_assert(false, "HERE2");
    }
    ...
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Constexpr if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_if) is supposed to work with template:

> Outside a template, a discarded statement is fully checked. `if constexpr` is not a substitute for the #if preprocessing directive:
>
> ```
> void f() {
>     if constexpr(false) {
>         int i = 0;
>         int *p = i; // Error even though in discarded statement
>     }
> }
> ```

And

> Note: the discarded statement can't be ill-formed for every possible specialization:
>
> ```
> template <typename T>
> void f() {
>      if constexpr (std::is_arithmetic_v<T>)
>          // ...
>      else
>        static_assert(false, "Must be arithmetic"); // ill-formed: invalid for every T
> }
> ```

You can wrap the code into a function template like:

```
template<class T> struct dependent_false : std::false_type {};
template <typename T>
void foo() {
    if constexpr (is_pair_type<T>::value)
    {
        std::cout << "HERE1" << "\n";
        static_assert(dependent_false<T>::value, "HERE1");
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "HERE2" << "\n";
        static_assert(dependent_false<T>::value, "HERE2");
    }
}
```

Then

```
using T = std::map<int, float>;
foo<T>(); // static_assert fails only on the else part
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/9qTUvZ4McxhQbaKw)

Comment: There is https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2023/p2593r1.html to allow `static_assert(false);`.